# Porque o Else não está sendo reconhecido nessa situação ? - JAVA

Tags: java, if, else

Tenho que usar `if` e `else` para demonstrar o valor final do desconto, mas está dando erro de *syntax*.

```
package Expressoes_Relacionais;
//ado03ex1

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Desconto_Loja {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Digite o valor total da compra");
        int TotalCompra = entrada.nextInt();

        if (TotalCompra >= 300);

        System.out.println("20% de desconto obtido");
        System.out.println("Valor total sem desconto "+ TotalCompra );
        System.out.println("Valor do desconto " + TotalCompra*0.20 );

        else (TotalCompra <= 299);

        System.out.println("15% de desconto obtido");
        System.out.println("Valor total sem desconto " + TotalCompra );
     }
}
```

Como resolver?

Comment: Bem-vindo ao [pt.so]! Você colocou uma imagem do código e/ou mensagem de erro. Apesar de parecer uma boa ideia, não é! Um dos motivos é que se alguém quiser responder a pergunta, não pode copiar o código e alterar algo dentro. Clique no link [edit] e **coloque o código/erro como texto**. Veja mais sobre isso nesses links - [Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5485/3774), [Postar mensagem de erro como imagem](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7816/3774)

Answer (score 2):

Ao se declarar uma condição `if`, por padrão, o analisador sintático espera que seja executado um bloco de código, sendo representado dentro de chaves `{bloco}`, ao omitir essas chaves, o JAVA, reconhece que só será efetuada a primeira instrução dentro da condição. Seguindo essa linha de raciocínio, o uso correto seria:

**Ao utilizar um bloco de código:**

```
if (condição) {
    bloco de código
}
else {
    bloco de código
}
```

**Uma única instrução:**

```
if (condição)
    instrução
else
    ...
```

Ao omitir o uso de chaves, e apresentar e seguida um bloco de código, a linguagem reconhece um erro sintático.

```
if(condicao)
    instrução
instrução
instrução
else //Aqui ocorre um erro sintático.
```